# SQL SERVER - Assign new values to a column according to an existing one

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server 2012 database I have a table with two columns, but their values are too long for an algorithm to handle.

The two columns´ values are IDs from another table that connect each other, like

```
A | B,
B | C,
D | A
```

I want to create 2 other columns on the same table with shorter values. How can I do that?

Basically, I want to translate something like

```
1234567890 | 0987654321, 
0987654321 | 5432167890
```

into

```
1 | 2,
2 | 3
```

for every row.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use a cursor operation to do this in order to guarantee that the new primary keys and foreign keys are the same for every row.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you explain more? When I "translate" one row, will the cursor know if one of the columns has been translated before and give it the same ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your data by using "cursor" object.

Please have a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I´ve read it, but I can´t really understand how can I use a cursor. Can you try and explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to split those into a table

```
Declare @t table(ID  INT IDENTITY , data varchar(max))
Insert into @t 
    Select '1234567890'  

;with cte as
(
  select ID,
         substring(data, 1, 1) as Chars,
         stuff(data, 1, 1, '') as data,
         1 as RowID
  from @t
  union all
  select ID,
         substring(data, 1, 1) as Chars,
         stuff(data, 1, 1, '') as data,
         RowID + 1 as RowID
  from cte
  where len(data) > 0
)
select  Chars
from cte
order by ID, RowID
```

Then you would need to create an expression in another column which either adds or increments to the current value in the current row.